# Get Buddypress style to display posts in user's profile tab

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, custom-post-type, buddypress

I really hope you can help me here because it's literally driving me crazy and keeping me from sleeping for 3 days now.
I've been looking everywhere to find a solution to my questioning and everytime I think I'm finally getting somewhere the answers are either too old or the links down, or when someone is facing the exact same issue they never get an answer.

SO. Here is the thing.
In my function.php I created a CPT so my users can create posts with WP User Frontend without polluting my blogs. Now, since the posts are in a CPT, they no longer show up in the built-in Posts tab that Buddypress provides. So, I then added a custom tab to display their posts on their profile.

And now it's getting messy.
I managed to get the posts from the CPT, everything works fine (I know it because if I echo the post thumbnail and title I see them). But I can't figure out how to get the freaking Buddypress template to style the posts list. I think I've read something like more than a hundred threads, I went through Wordpress and Buddypress codex, I even dug into my Buddypress plugin files to find the templates and blog loops and try to understand how it works. But still, nothing.

Here is the code I have so far

```
function bp_costumes_tab_setup_nav() {
    global $bp;
    $parent_slug = 'profil-costumes';
    
    bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
    'name' => 'Costumes tab',
    'slug' => $parent_slug,
    'parent_url' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $parent_slug.'/',
    'screen_function' => 'costumes_tab_show_screen',
    'position' => 3,
    'default_subnav_slug' => 'profil-costumes'
    ) );
    }
    
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'bp_costumes_tab_setup_nav' );
    
    function costumes_tab_show_screen() {   
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'bptab_costumes_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/plugins' ) );
    }
    
function bptab_costumes_content() {
    
    $myposts = get_posts(  array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // set the number of post to show, -1 if all
    'author'         => bp_displayed_user_id(),
    'post_type'      => 'cptgalerie',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_status'      => 'publish'
    ));
    
    if( ! empty( $myposts ) ) { 
    
        foreach($myposts as $post) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
             
             **HERE I WANT THE POSTS FROM CPT TO BE DISPLAYED LIKE IN THE BUILT-IN POSTS TAB**
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();    
            } else { 
    
    echo '<div class="info" id="message">
    <p>Aucun album publié.</p>      
    </div>';
        }
    }
```

As I'm using Elementor Pro I also tried creating a loop and add the shortcode in my php with

```
echo do_shortcode ("[elementor-template ID='xxx']");
```

but it gets the template without the post info. It just keeps repeating the user's name (which is technically the "post title" since I used the "post title" widget in my template, I know, but it's not the title I want). Here too I tried to understand how it works by digging into another plugin I use that gets Elementor templates to display posts.

I found other answers where "if ( ! empty...)" is replaced by "if (have posts)... while" but it doesn't seem to work. I've read also that now the "bp_core_load_template" should be replaced by something else... many tests but no results. I also found that it has something to do with some archive template.
I'm lost.

Please, pleeeeeaaaase, can someone help me?
I need to sort it out, get it out of my mind and SLEEP.

Thank you!

Comment: Nhayaa can you not just copy the exact html from inpsect element of browser and design same page like buddy press is offering and then display your posts there?

Comment: Shaniawan, thank you for your response.
The funny thing with asking for help is that when you do it, you find the solution.
I went back digging into my Buddypress/Youzify files and finally found the file I needed to modify the code above and call the template with a "require_once". Which leaves me with another problem now but for this one, it's all good! Finally!